# How to Mock Load Balancing Environment for a WCF Service?

Tags: wcf, testing, mocking, load-balancing

Please let me know if there is there anyway to Mock a Load Balancing Env. for testing WCF Services?

Thanks
PV

Comment: Can you give more indication as to the load balancing configuration you're using? I'm guessing you'd be using the windows server NLB tools, but I'd like to double check. Also, is the WCF 'stuff' stateless? (i.e. is SQL Server session management, or similar, going to be required as a part of this test?)

Comment: sorry for the delay. I am not sure of how the load balancing env. is configured but we used f5 load balancer. yes WCF stuff is stateless.

Comment: I'm in a (very!) similar situation. I'm sorry I can't add much more to the question, but it's *definitely* worth knowing what load balancer you're using, as, depending on the aim of the tests, this could be a crucial part of testing correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt Snider, the former PM of the WCF Routing mechanism blogged about a solution here:
 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/routingrules/archive/2010/04/14/load-balancing-at-the-routing-service.aspx

The sample he mention is a part of the WCF/WF 4.0 Samples Pack (which can be downloaded here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35EC8682-D5FD-4BC3-A51A-D8AD115A8792) is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667249%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

--larsw